# Oracle join to either of multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a RELATION table

```
NUM1 | NUM2 | NUM3
 --   ---   -----
 1     2     3    
 2     4     5
 3     4     null
 3     4     null
```

and the actual INFO table where NUM is primary key.

```
 NUM | A_LOT_OF_OTHER_INFO
 ---  --------------------
   1     asdff    
   2     werwr
   3     erert
   4     ghfgh
   5     cvbcb
```

I want to create a view to see the count of the NUM that appeared in any of the NUM1, NUM2, NUM3 of the RELATION table.

MY_VIEW

```
 NUM | A_LOT_OF_OTHER_INFO | TOTAL_COUNT
 ---  --------------------  ------------
   1     asdff                  1
   2     werwr                  2
   3     erert                  3
   4     ghfgh                  3
   5     cvbcb                  1
```

I can do this by doing three selects from RELATION table and UNION them, but I do not want to use UNION because the tables have a lot of records, MY_VIEW is already large enough and I am looking for a better way to join to the RELATION table in the view. Can you suggest a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i would try is to unpivot the relation table.

After that join the info table on the values and count the number of times the val gets repeated.

```
create table relation(num1 int,num2 int, num3 int);

insert into relation values(1,2,3);
insert into relation values(2,4,5);
insert into relation values(3,4,null);

create table info(num int, a_lot_of_other_info varchar2(100));
insert into info
   select 1,'asdff' from dual union all
   select 2,'werwr' from dual union all
   select 3,'erert' from dual union all
   select 4,'ghfgh' from dual union all
   select 5,'cvbcb' from dual 

 select a.num
        ,max(a_lot_of_other_info) as a_lot_of_other_info
        ,count(*) as num_of_times
   from info a
   join (select val
           from relation a
         unpivot(val for x in (num1,num2,num3))
         )b
      on a.num=b.val  
 group by a.num 
 order by 1
```

Comment: Note that the OP wants to keep the other column from `INFO`, too; arranging the query this way will not allow him to do that. (Also, the query will produce the correct count for each `NUM` only if `NUM` does not have duplicates in `INFO`; perhaps that's the case, it certainly is in the sample provided, but that's something to keep in mind regardless.)

Comment: Agreed, i have inlcuded the column  a_lot_of_other_info now and yes, i assumed that NUM column is unique

Comment: I used the approach here and did not need to use MAX(a_lot_of_other_info), since   it was sure that NUM is unique and no repeating rows.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
select i.*,
       (select ((case when r.num1 = i.num then 1 else 0 end) +
                (case when r.num2 = i.num then 1 else 0 end) +
                (case when r.num3 = i.num then 1 else 0 end)
               )
        from relation r
        where i.num in (r.num1, r.num2, r.num3)
       ) as total_count
from info i;
```

If performance is a consideration, it might be faster to use `left join`s:

```
select i.*,
       ((case when r1.num1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when r2.num1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when r3.num1 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as total_count
from info i left join
     relation r1
     on i.num = r1.num1 left join
     relation r2
     on i.num = r2.num2 left join
     relation r3
     on i.num = r3.num3;
```

In particular, this will make optimal use of three separate indexes on `relation`:  `relation(num1)`, `relation(num2)`, and `relation(num3)`.

Comment: This will show in how many rows the number appears, but it will not count the appearances themselves. If a row has all three column values equal to 1, then the OP wants a count of 3, not of 1.

Comment: Would not the first run for each of the rows in the INFO table?

Comment: @mathguy we are sure that NUM1 NUM2 NUM3 are different or null, thanks for the notification though.

Comment: @mathguy . . . (1) That only applied to the first query.  (2) It is now fixed.

Comment: The second query reads the base table three times, exactly what the OP wanted to avoid.

Comment: @mCeviker . . . Yes, but since you have no filtering on that table, all the rows are in the result set anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you want is UNPIVOT. Perhaps easiest to do with a cross join in this case:

```
select   NUM, count(*) as TOTAL_COUNT
from     ( 
           select decode(column_value, 1, NUM1, 2, NUM2, 3, NUM3) as NUM
           from   RELATION cross join table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3))
         )
group by NUM
;
```

Then join this to the second table; the join part is really irrelevant here.

Comment: [Code: 904, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00904: "NUM": invalid identifier <-- I got this in the group by statement

Comment: @mCeviker - Sorry, I had the GROUP BY clause in the wrong place; it should be in the outer query, of course, not in the subquery.

Comment: Correct. Sorry, I figured that out but forgot to update here.